# jpa can't execute a simple query

Tags: java, jpa, db2, openjpa

I have to retrieve data from a table in db2 using jpa 
after all configuration and mapping 
when I try to execute a query using the entity manager I get errors don't know where is the problem exactly.
 the message error :`Error 500: <openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1141200 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.CATEGORIE, DRIVER=4.8.86 {prepstmnt 85179437 SELECT t0.CODE_CAT, t0.LIBELLE_CAT FROM CATEGORIE t0 } [code=-204, state=42704]SQLCA OUTPUT[Errp=SQLNQ1FC, Errd=-2145779603, 0, 0, 0, -10, 0] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.CATEGORIE, DRIVER=4.8.86 DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-204;42704;DB2ADMIN.CATEGORIE, DRIVER=4.8.86 DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-204;42704;DB2ADMIN.CATEGORIE, DRIVER=4.8.86 FailedObject: select c from Categorie c [java.lang.String]`

Comment: Go through the questions you've asked and accept the answer using the check mark under the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and i resolved it by adding Schema in my entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MyTable", schema="MySchemaName")
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [SQLSTATE messages page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html), the first error (SQLCODE=`-204`, SQLSTATE=`42704`) is "An undefined object or constraint name was detected".  The second error (SQLCODE=`-727`, SQLSTATE=`56098`) is "An error occurred during implicit rebind, recompile, or revalidation.", which probably stems from the `-204`.

`-204` usually means that either the table name is spelled wrong, or it can't find the table for some reason.  I don't see a schema on the SQL generated there (`SELECT t0.CODE_CAT, t0.LIBELLE_CAT FROM CATEGORIE t0`), so perhaps you need to add that.

Comment: thanks for your reply I added the schema annotation on the class the schema name is "AYMEN" the error has changed:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-551;42501;DB2ADMIN|SELECT|AYMEN.CATEGORIE, DRIVER=4.8.86
I think it's a problem in privielges

Comment: Can you please post full stack trace.